# C# + IE9 JS Engine Chakra?

Tags: c#, javascript, internet-explorer, chakra

I'm working on a cool C# app, which uses JS a lot for our model layer.
We would like to use the IE9 Chakra Javascript engine for speed improvements.

**Questions:**

- Can I use Chakra in C#, and interact with JS objects as COM objects? (to call functions on JS objects)
- Can I install Chakra separately from IE9? (some users do not have IE9 installed, so it would be easier if they did not have to install IE9, but just Chakra).

Thanks a lot in advance for you expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Update] Based on Cheeso's answer it seems you can use IE9's JS engine[/Update]. However I found that [V8 JavaScript engine (Chrome's JS engine)](http://code.google.com/p/v8/) mentions that you can use V8 engine  in you C++ application. Follow [V8 embedder's guide](http://code.google.com/apis/v8/embed.html) to find out more. I did not find any reference where they mentioned exposing V8 functionality through COM interface, so you might not be able to use it from C#.

Comment: Bump. Any news about this? Have you heard any updates from MS about the possibility for this in the future?

Comment: No, I don't have any such information. Have you checked http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp? Would that be useful to you?

Comment: This answer is wrong.  It *is possible* to interact with the IE9 JS engine.  See my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429749/c-ie9-js-engine-chakra/7433549#7433549

Answer (score 7):

### Answer to Q#1

*Yes, you can* interact with Javascript logic running in Chakra from C# via COM.

in Particular, from a c# program, you can startup Chakra via IActiveScript, load some Javascript/ES5 code into it, then invoke methods defined in that Javascript code via a COM IDispatch pointer.

Related:

- [Will the IE10 Chakra JScript engine available as stand alone accessible from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939002/will-the-ie10-chakra-jscript-engine-available-as-stand-alone-accessible-from-c/7367964#7367964)
- [What is the ProgId or CLSID for IE9's Javascript engine (code-named "Chakra")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167690)

### Answer to Q#2

As far as I know, NO, you cannot install Chakra without installing IE9.  You can design your C# app, though, to gracefully degrade to use the existing JScript engine, for computers without Chakra.

Comment: Can you please help me with this question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48150043/getting-unable-to-load-chakra-core-dll-error-while-running-hello-world-sample